Failed to Resolve Kotlin JVM Plugin Version 1.7.1 in Flutter Project with Gradle implementing stripe
I'm working on a Flutter project and encountered a build failure related to the Kotlin JVM plugin when trying to build my app. Here is the error message I received:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\build.gradle.kts' line: 5

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.7.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:



Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.1')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
android/build.gradle file
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}



def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    namespace "com.example.chaeffur_app"
    compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.chaeffur_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {}

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }
    settings.ext.flutterSdkPath = flutterSdkPath()

    includeBuild("${settings.ext.flutterSdkPath}/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"

my build.gradle.kts file
// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.1"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
}

group = "dev.flutter.plugin"
version = "1.0.0"

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        // The "flutterPlugin" name isn't used anywhere.
        create("flutterPlugin") {
            id = "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
            implementationClass = "FlutterPlugin"
        }
        // The "flutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin" name isn't used anywhere.
        create("flutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin") {
            id = "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader"
            implementationClass = "FlutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // When bumping, also update:
    //  * ndkVersion in FlutterExtension in packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
    //  * AGP version in the buildscript block in packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
    //  * AGP version in the buildscript block in packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/kotlin/dependency_version_checker.gradle.kts
    //  * AGP version constants in packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/gradle_utils.dart
    compileOnly("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0")
}

i am unable to build the project now. i dont know wh is this happening i tried many solution tried changing the versions too.. but dont know why is this hapening.Is there something I need to configure differently in my build.gradle.kts or elsewhere to resolve this issue?
